# Laravel - Calling relationship within query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a many to many relationship between Users and Clients:

User.php

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class);
}
```

Client.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

In my app I want the authenticated user to be able to see a list of all users associated with all the clients they themselves can see - which would of course include themselves.

Get the Authenticated user. Find their clients. Then find the users of those clients. Something like this:

```
$user = auth('api')->user();
$users = $user->client->user;
return $users;
```

This syntax is of course incorrect, but I hope it shows the idea of what I'm trying to do! What's the correct/best way of pulling this data out? Is it even possible in one eloquent query?

The longer way would be to get the client, run a loop for each client pulling out a collection of the user objects, and then combining the collections.

```
$user = auth('api')->user();
$clients = $user->client;
$users_collection = new Collection();

foreach($clients as $client){
    $new_collection = $client->user;
    $users_collection = $users_collection->merge($new_collection);
}
return($users_collection);
```

I'm wondering if there's a shorter, more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

With these 2 relationships defined (note the plural since they are many to many relationships):

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'db_table');
}


public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'db_table');
}
```

`db_table` is the relationiships database table with at least 2 columns, `user_id` and `client_id`.
You can get users with this code:

```
$users = Client::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->where('db_table.user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->users;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This doesn't seem to work for me though. It throws this error from the SQL:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` inner join `client_user` on `users`.`id` = `client_user`.`user_id` where `clients`.`id` = `client_user`.`client_id` and `client_user`.`user_id` = 1)

It's looking for clients.id - but that table isn't part of the query.

Comment: write on the post the structure of your database